# Find a normal vector using cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Am I doing this right?

If a plane contains the points *A = (2, 2, 3), B = (1, 0, 1) and C = (−1, 3, 4)*,  find a normal vector by using cross product.

- 1) First I find a cross product for AB
- 2) Find a cross product for BC
- 3) Then find a cross product for *AB* and *BC*

Is this correct way to do this?

Comment: You only need to find one cross product...

Comment: Oh... What do you mean? Only cross product for AB and BC? And solve AB and BC other way?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the three points $A = (2, 2, 3), B = (1, 0, 1)$, and $C = (−1, 3, 4)$, which lie on a plane. Then the vectors 
$$
AB=\mathcal{O}B-\mathcal{O}A=\langle 1, 0, 1 \rangle - \langle  2, 2, 3\rangle
= \langle 1-2, 0-2, 1-3 \rangle = \langle -1, -2, -2\rangle
$$
and 
$$
BC=\mathcal{O}C-\mathcal{O}B= \langle −1, 3, 4 \rangle - \langle 1, 0, 1 \rangle =  \langle −1-1, 3-0, 4-1 \rangle 
= \langle -2,3,3\rangle 
$$
are two vectors that are parallel to the plane, where $\mathcal{O}A$ is the position vector from the origin $(0,0,0)$ to the point $A$ (similar with $\mathcal{O}B$ and $\mathcal{O}C$). 
Note that $AB$ and $BC$ are non-parallel.

Then the cross product of $AB$ and $BC$ is: 
$$
\boxed{AB\times BC = \langle 0,7,-7 \rangle},  
$$ 
which is perpendicular to the two vectors $AB$ and $BC$. So it is normal to the plane.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with your first two steps. All you have to do is to compute $AB\times AC$.

Comment: Okay, now I am puzzled. 

I mean I make a matrix where is A and B. Then I make a matrix where is A and C. And then AB x AC. Thats what I meant. Is that correct?

Comment: @MiMaKo What's your doubt? Compute $AB\times AC$ and you'll get a vector wich is normal to the plane defined by $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: I guess I have problems understanding mathematical methodology and/or "language"

Comment: I will try to put it in other terms. Let $v=AB\times AC $. Let $D=A+v$. Then $AD$ is orthogonal to the plane.